# Are Chinese trends being mislabeled as Japanese or Korean?

Tags: china, internet, social-media, culture

I'm seeing claims like this in various places on the Internet:

> Some Chinese trends such as Douyin and Xiaohongshu makeup, specific styles of makeup originating from and named after Chinese social media apps, have managed to gain traction on American social media.
>
> However, these trends have been mislabeled as Japanese or Korean; cultures that already have their own respective styles. This miscrediting is a false representation and attribution of East Asian cultures. This is specifically a problem when it comes to attributing Chinese culture and is due to sinophobia.
>
> ...
>
> The erasure of Chinese culture in preference of more desirable East Asian cultures like Japan and South Korea has been an increasing issue in the media.
> <sub>Daphne So, [Asian trends mislabeled](https://www.thecalifornianpaper.com/2023/04/asian-trends-mislabeled/), The Californian, April 2023.</sub>

A comparable article is Ye Ji Jong, [*Disregarding Douyin makeup’s origin breeds Sinophobia*](https://dailytrojan.com/2023/09/11/disregarding-douyin-makeups-origin-breeds-sinophobia/), September 2023.  The claim is also spreading on social media: e.g. [this](https://www.tiktok.com/@candiselin86/video/7321575185285385518), [this](https://www.tiktok.com/@baibai6611/video/7201214926591970603), [this](https://twitter.com/_maihan/status/1748211850402250966), or [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/asianamerican/comments/17q5wtj/im_chinese_american_and_im_jealous_of_japanese/).  These pertain to makeup, but there's comparable claims about other cultural products:

> Anything cool that comes out of China gets quickly rebranded as Japanese or Korean on the western side of the internet- you see it all the time on TikTok, and I often see posters on XiaoHongShu lamenting when their art and photography gets reposted on western social media and tagged #japaneseaesthetic or #koreanaesthetic
> <sub>u/mintyinks at [Reddit's r/ChineseLanguage](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/1bdg6qy/comment/kumdhpx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button), March 2024.</sub>

The general claim is that Chinese "trends" are being mislabeled as Japanese or Korean.  The reasons I saw listed online were a combination of: (a) to attract more clicks, (b) sinophobia, and (c) they don't know the difference between Chinese, Japanese, and Korean culture.

I wasn't immediately able to find concrete examples/evidence that this is happening.  [This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/3Jg-mR0dK8c?si=B6woEKZoxXxATcCi&t=242) mentions a TikTok which lists Chinese trends but doesn't pinpoint where they're being mislabeled; the TikTok also compares the Google Image Search results for [`korean nails`](https://www.google.com/search?q=korean+nails&tbm=isch) vs. [`chinese nails`](https://www.google.com/search?q=chinese+nails&tbm=isch), and the TikTok commenter thought a hit for `korean nails` with the 小红书 (XiaoHongShu) watermark were actually Chinese nails.

The amount of commentary on the topic suggests it's a widespread problem.

**Question**: Are Chinese trends being mislabeled as Japanese or Korean?

Comment: Are you looking for art examples and would this count? On SFF, there are [dozens of \[story-identification\] questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Manhua+manhwa) that are looking for a manga or manhua or manhwa—OP has no idea which. There are still more that pick one term and it's the wrong one. (Note that tag [manga] is used as an umbrella term.)

Comment: Would it be better to concentrate on a specific trend/style, with a specific claim about that style, and investigate the origin of that style? Otherwise it could be a very diffuse answer - I'd be surprised if there is nothing that doesn't have some small Chinese origin but that wouldn't prove that it's a significant issue.

Comment: Lots of things are regularly mislabelled: for example in the Sinosphere [Singapore noodles - a rice vermicelli stir-fry dish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore-style_noodles) - were named as such in Hong Kong because they include curry, but did not come from Singapore.

Comment: Mislabeling is extremely common: Never attribute to malice what can equally be explained by stupidity. American indigenous people are called "Indians" not because Columbus was malicious: he was just an idiot.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @Hilmar here.  The general public in America aren't great at identifying different countries (India vs Pakistan, Thailand vs Laos, any country in the Middle East, Mexico and any South American country).  I've even seen Korean/Japanese things incorrectly attributed to China.  This seems less malicious and more uninformed or lazy.